# jQuery not detecting click on link in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link inside a table that I would like to do something once clicked, but jQuery doesn't seem to be able to detect that for some reason.

It works fine when I have an `onclick="..."` on the link.

I also figured out I can't detect clicks on td/tr elements (`$('td').click(function(){});`), I'm assuming that that's due to the element being inside the table.

But when I try to get the link element (`$('#requested-link')`) it works fine.

How can I solve this?

I already tried with a higher z-index on link elements, that didn't work.

**EDIT:**

Here is the part of my code that should catch the clicking of the link

```
 $('.js-remove_baustein_from_versicherung').on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
        console.log('link was clicked');
    });
```

This is the table:

```
     <table class="table table-striped" id="bausteinTable">
        <tr id="versicherung_baustein_3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Versicherung1</td>
            <td><a class="js-remove_baustein_from_versicherung" baustein_id="3" href="">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="versicherung_baustein_6">
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Versicherung2</td>
            <td><a class="js-remove_baustein_from_versicherung" baustein_id="6" href="">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

A test to see, if jQuery actually 'sees' the element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        console.log($('.js-remove_baustein_from_versicherung'));
    })
```

and this is the output:

```
jQuery.fn.init [a.js-remove_baustein_from_versicherung]
```

**EDIT 2:**

Please give me back my posting rights?

Comment: Can you show some revelant part of your code ?

Comment: *"I'm assuming that that's due to the element being inside the table"* - Assuming is not the same thing as debugging.  Please provide a minimal example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MaximeGirou I added the table and the code that catches the click

Comment: @David I added the code that isn't working, the table and a test for checking if jQuery 'sees' the element

Comment: @ChristianGröber: You're re-using the same `id` in your HTML, making the markup invalid and the JavaScript behavior undefined.  In my browser the click event is being handled just fine by the first matching element, but not the second.

Answer (score 1):

**You use the same ID in your `<td>`**

Use class instead of id because two elements cannot have the same ID

Get the id from the event.target attribute with [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName)

and then use the [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function with jquery to remove the line you want

```js
$('.remove_baustein_from_versicherung').on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('DETECTED');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="bausteinTable">
  <tr class="versicherung_baustein_3">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Versicherung1</td>
    <td><a class="remove_baustein_from_versicherung" baustein_id="3" href="">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="versicherung_baustein_6">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Versicherung2</td>
    <td><a class="remove_baustein_from_versicherung" baustein_id="6" href="">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I edited my post. Sadly using a class instead of an id doesn't seem to work either

Comment: @ChristianGröber look at my snippet, it's working, i use a silly modified version of your code why not yours ?